# Test if there are any matches between two CSV-strings?

Tags: vba

rCell1 contains CSV delimited text, such as "Skyscraper, Big House, Small house". I want to check if any of those match any of the comma delimited values in rCell2. Examples of what rCell2 can contain is "Big House, Big Dog, Big Rock".

Details:
* It is also possible that either rCell1 or rCell2 do not contain any commas.
* If either rCell1 or rCell2 are blank then we have no match. 
* Spaces at the beginning and end of substrings should be ignored.

Is there any smart way to performing this in VBA?

The following is code that works, but it would match "House" and "Big House", which I don't want to do.

```
If rCell = "" Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    For Each vCriteria In vCriteriaArray
        If InStr(1, "," & rCell.Value & ",", "," & vCriteria & ",", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            bMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vCriteria
    If Not bMatch Then rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: this question should now be marked as answered

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use the Split function: `myArray1() = Split(rCell1, ",")` to...split the strings into an array. Then sort both arrays for more efficient comparison loop.

Option 2: (eventually using `Split` again) add all sub-items of rcell1 to a collection, then try adding all sub-items of rcell2 to the same collection. Duplicates will clash and create an error.

Answer (score 0):

This splits by comma and enters the values into 2 arrays, then iterates through the arrays to check for matches.

You also use the System.Collections.ArrayList object for a faster comparison as this has a boolean `.Cointains` method which can be accessed.

Here is a solutions using the `Split()` function.

```
vArr1 = Split(rCell1, ",")
vArr2 = Split(rCell2, ",")

For Each vItem1 In vArr1
   For Each vItem2 In vArr2
     If vItem1 = vItem2 Then
     bMatch = True
     Exit For
   Next vItem2
If bMatch Then Exit For
Next vItem 1
```